# input does not appear in firefox

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I test a system that only works in IE, if I run it in Firefox, a single entry (cpfField) , does not appear on the page and consego not identify because of this, but in IE, gives much trouble in the tests.
Is there a way around this behavior page to run tests in Firefox?

Code in Firefox:

```
<input type="text" name="cpf" maxlength="11" size="15" value="" class="textbox" id="cpfField">
```

Code in IE11:

```
<INPUT id=cpfField class=textbox maxLength=11 size=15 name=cpf>
```

[image]

Comment: Is your page need refresh for your task

Comment: @ShubhamJain There is no need to reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an attribute in an HTML run time using javascript. If your page is not going to reload then this value will not remove. I am not sure but you can have try with same.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
WebElement element = driver.findElement(Your Locator);
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('id', 'cpfField')",element);
```

Now try to click your button

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: In fact do not need to click anything , I just need preemcher this input , how do?